# PowerShell Switch Statement - Missing statement block in switch statement clause Error

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I have a PowerShell script that grabs file data and generates a checksum script (also PowerShell) we use to validate UI changes with software deployments.

I inserted a switch statement into this script to identify the server type I was running this generation script on and name the outed generated checksum file accordingly. It does so by checking a registry key value on these servers that identifies the server type (Alpha, Beta, etc). The switch names are the names of these registry key values.

With this switch statement, I receive a `Missing statement block in switch statement clause` error.

What I noticed when I looked at this script in the PowerShell ISE, is that there is a color difference between the `2008` (dark purple) and the `_Server_Alpha` (lighter purple) as if the switch name starting with numbers or having the underscores is throwing it off? If I comment out those two switches so that just the default remains, it works great.

```
$serverkey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\CompanyName'
$servertype = (Get-ItemProperty $serverkey "Server Type")."Server Type"

$file = switch ($servertype)
{
2008_Server_Alpha {"\\server\AppChecksum_Alpha.ps1"}
2008_Server_Beta {"\\server\AppChecksum_Beta.ps1"}
default {"\\server\New_AppChecksum.ps1"}
}
```

And then at the end of the script I have the `out-file $file` that will call this switch to see how to out the generated file.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine. I just assigned a hardcoded string to `$servertype` to test it.

An alternative would be to use a hashtable to look up the value for each server type. It's not shorter, but more intuitive in my mind:

```
$servertype = '2008_Server_Alpha'

$servertypes = @{'2008_Server_Alpha' = '\\server\AppChecksum_Alpha.ps1'
                 '2008_Server_Beta' = '\\server\AppChecksum_Beta.ps1'}

# look up the value for this servertype if there is one
if ($servertypes.Contains($servertype)) {
    $file = $servertypes[$servertype]
} else {
    $file = '\\server\New_AppChecksum.ps1'
}
```

Comment: Hmm...ok I will play around with this and see if I can get this to work. Thanks.